# Working of Domain and sub-domain names of websites

Tags: web-services, dns, subdomain

How do sub-domain names work?

Actually I want to develop platform for `CV`s and I bought a domain `www.cv.com`. Now I want the url for each user with his/her name like `www.john.cv.com` or `www.cv.john.com`.

Does single domain work for this case or do I have to buy the sub-domains too? How is it managed programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`www.john.cv.com` will work.  Will you have to buy or not depends on your domain name provider and packages. In maximum cases atmost 5 sub domain is free if you need further you have to pay certain price.